# Xtragrid: Apply custom filter without rebinding the datasource

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using Xtragrid control and BindingList as data source, and CustomRowFilter event of gridView control. It works fine when I call BindingList.ResetBindings, but it resets the current selection.

Is there a way to force new filter (through CustomRowFilter event handler) without calling BindingList.ResetBindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [RefreshDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl%5fRefreshDataSourcetopic) method to update data displayed within the grid control's View as:

```
 //Refresh the grid control 
 gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
```

I suggest you to go through the below reference links:
[Refreshing the GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument754)
[GridControl.RefreshDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl%5fRefreshDataSourcetopic)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself:

```
xtraGrid.RefreshDataSource()
```